# Create column based on regex matching without extraction

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark

I have a massive amount fo file list like this :

```
file.txt
file.txt.tar.gz
file.txt.tgz
core123165
core123165.bak
file.jpg
file.jpg.bak
file.png
file.png.tgz
...
```

There are a lot of cases I cannot list them all.
I would like to deduce file type based on there extension or file name.
Problem is I would like to ignore a set of extension such as `tgz` or `bak`, So far here's my idea:

```
val DF = spark.createDF(
  List(("file.txt"),("file.txt.tar.gz"),("file.txt.tgz"),
      ("core123165"),("core123165.bak"),("file.jpg"),
      ("file.jpg.bak"),("file.png"),("file.png.tgz")),
  List(("name", StringType, true))
  )

DF.withColumn("type",
when($"name".endsWith(".txt"), "text").
when($"name".endsWith(".txt.tar.gz"), "text").
when($"name".endsWith(".txt.tgz"), "text").
when($"name".endsWith(".txt.bz2"), "text").
when[...]
)
```

And so on, however I will need to use regex to identify core file with something like `^core[0-9]{6}$` and would like to use regex to identify other type more easily using something like `^.+\.txt$|^.+\.txt.zip$|^.+\.txt.gz$`.
So my question is is there a Spark/Scala method applicable to column to do something like :

```
val DF = spark.createDF(
  List(("file.txt"),("file.txt.tar.gz"),("file.txt.tgz"),
      ("core123165"),("core123165.bak"),("file.jpg"),
      ("file.jpg.bak"),("file.png"),("file.png.tgz")),
  List(("name", StringType, true))
  )

DF.withColumn("type",
when($"name".matches("^.+\.txt$|^.+\.txt.zip$|^.+\.txt.gz$|^.+\.txt.bz2$^.+\.txt.tar.gz$^.+\.txt.tgz$"), "text").
when($"name".matches("^core[0-9]{6}$|^core[0-9]{6}\.bak$"), "core")
[...]
)
```

This would greatly improve my treatment.

I know I could factorize my regex even more using `^.+\.txt(\.bak|\.tgz|\.bz2)$` but it was just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rlike` is the function you are looking for.

Also, you need to escape the backslashes `\` with another backslash: `\\`. This would look like this:

```
df.withColumn("type",
   when('name rlike "^.+\\.txt$|^.+\\.txt.zip$", "text").otherwise("other"))
```

Comment: I saw that you wanted to replace `'name rlike ""` by `$"name".rlike ""`. Note that both syntaxes are correct as long as you import `spark.implicits._`

Comment: oh, I didn't know that thanks for the information :-)